# Excluding a element from ngFor for the Overlay

Tags: angular, ngfor

currently im having a issue with my OverlayPanel. Im trying to make a overlay panel with specific details about the person im currently hovering. The problem is that im creating the whole table of users with ngFor, so the overlaypanel shows for each person instead of the single one i wanted.

I tried already tried ngIf but i didnt work

```html
<tr *ngFor="let person of personsFiltered | async">
                <td> <a [routerLink]='"pDetails/" + person.personId' (mouseenter)="isOpen = !isOpen" cdkOverlayOrigin #trigger="cdkOverlayOrigin"> Details </a> </td>   
                 //the overlay which should open one time
                 // and the wrong ngIf statement
                 // person.personId gets the single person
                <ng-template *ngIf="personsFiltered != person" cdkConnectedOverlay [cdkConnectedOverlayOrigin]="trigger" [cdkConnectedOverlayOpen]="isOpen" >
                    {{person.vorname}}
                </ng-template>
                <td> </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the names are being shown because you use a single boolean variable to decide when to show all of them. I would keep the `id` of the person you are currently hovering and only show that:

In your `.ts` file:

```
public hoveredPersonId: number | null;
```

and in your template file:

```html
<tr *ngFor="let person of personsFiltered | async">
  <td>
    <a
      [routerLink]="'pDetails/' + person.personId"
      (mouseenter)="hoveredPersonId = person.personId"
      (mouseleave)="hoveredPersonId = null"
      cdkOverlayOrigin
      #trigger="cdkOverlayOrigin">
      Details
    </a>
  </td>

  <ng-template
    *ngIf="person.personId === hoveredPersonId"
    cdkConnectedOverlay
    [cdkConnectedOverlayOrigin]="trigger"
    cdkConnectedOverlayOpen>
    {{ person.vorname }}
  </ng-template>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your if condition seems wrong, shouldn't it be like this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let person of personsFiltered | async">
            <td> 
                 <a [routerLink]='"pDetails/" + person.personId' (mouseenter)="isOpen = !isOpen" cdkOverlayOrigin #trigger="cdkOverlayOrigin"> Details </a> 
            </td>   

            <ng-template *ngIf="person.vorname != 'NAME OF PERSON YOU WISH TO EXCLUDE'" cdkConnectedOverlay [cdkConnectedOverlayOrigin]="trigger" [cdkConnectedOverlayOpen]="isOpen" >
                {{person.vorname}}
            </ng-template>
</tr>
```

Comment: i tried it already like this "person.personId != personsFiltered.personId" but same result. person is the single person and personsFiltered are all persons

Comment: You are still wrong, if you are looping over `personsFiltered` then how can you compare with `personsFiltered.personId`. It should be a specific value.